# Laravel calendar of absences problem with displaying in table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanted to create team calendar of absences. Each user can define more than one absence in specific month.

Then I want to print it for each in table like this (example for 10 days):

```
Day   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
-----------------------------------------------|
User1 | o | o | x | x | x | x | o | o | o | x  |
-----------------------------------------------|
User2 | x | o | o | o | x | x | o | x | o | x  |
-----------------------------------------------|
```

Where the "o" is for normal day and "x" is defined as absence.

I got Users table and Absences table:

```
Users
id | name 

Absences
id | user_id | start | end
```

I get the current month day value and iterate through all Users and then through the days in blade like that:

```
@foreach ($users as $user )
   <tr>
      <td> {{ $user->name }} </td>
   @if($user->absences != null)
      @foreach($days as $day)
         @foreach ($user->absences as $absence)
           @if($day >= $absence->start->format('d') && $day <= $absence->end->format('d'))
              <td style="background: red"> x </td>
           @else
              <td style="background: blue"> o </td>
           @endif
         @endforeach
       @endforeach
    @endif
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

The problem is that, If user have more than one absence defined, the days in his column are doubled and whole table is being crashed. When User has only 1 absence, it works OK.

Do you have any idea how do achieve that easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in `@foreach ($user->absences as $absence)` loop. You're checking all the absences for one day.

Instead, you should use a function to get all the absense days of users. I think keeping such functionality in controller is a better idea.

```
$users = $users->map(function ($user) {
    $user['absenseDays'] = $user->absences->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
        return [...$carry, ...range($item['start'], $item['end'])];
    }, []);
    return $user;
});
```

This should create a new entry of absenseDays on each user, and the values should be an array of absense days. Let's say a user has 2 records 5-8 and 12-14, absenseDays should be [5,6,7,8,12,13,14].

In blade you need only:

```
@if (in_array($day, $user->absenseDays))
    <td style="background: red"> x </td>
@else
    <td style="background: blue"> o </td>
@endif
```

I wrote the function here directly. So it might not work, or can be a better way to produce the same output. But I can say that for sure, producing absenseDays array is the best approach that I can come up with.

Comment: These new entry (absenceDays) should be an array of merged f.e. 3 objects of absences of specific user? I mean it should be function in controller?

Comment: Yes, merge the ranges between start/end. Also yes, because Blade shouldn't contain such logic. I actially wouldn't event put it into controller. Creating a seperate class and calling the class method from controller is a better idea.

Comment: For test I've put your function into the controller section and it say's "Call to undefined method App\Models\User::put()". I'm doing it on "$users = User::with('absences')->get()" collection. I'm probably not right?

Comment: I updated the function. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Seems to be working, but I've needed to add "range($item['start']->format('d'), $item['end'])->format('d)]" , because of problem with Carbon convertion. Is it also possible to adjust it for different color? I mean I wanted also to have "reason_id" in Absence table. For example "Vacation" or "Training" in Reason table. I want to compare it in View f.e. in switch/case. Something need to be changed?

Comment: Also found problem if User selects previous month of starting absence and ends in current, which displays it wrong

Comment: is the possibility to add to that array also the reason_id and deputy_id for each day?

Comment: To add reasons, instead of creating an array of days, make days the keys and add reason as value. To handle previous month, the best way will be calculate the days between the data and the starting of the previos month. What do you ask here is all about how to structure your data array. It's not about laravel. Yes you can add whatever you want. Let's say days 2-3. Make this [2 => ['reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3], 3 => ['reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3]] or this [[day => 2, 'reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3], [day => 3, 'reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3]].

Comment: I resolved problem with days of previous month, checking if start month < end month. If yes, then start day is set it to the 1st day of end month.

Does adding another columns(reason_id, deputy_id) is hard to achieve from previous function structure?

Comment: it's qiute easy.

Comment: Can you instruct me a little bit? I assume I need an array of each day of absence, then another array inside it?

Comment: I gave you a proper array structure in my previous comment already. You can work on it. Sİnce your question is answered correctly, we need stop here. If you need any other help, create a new question specificly for that issue. Please accept the answer so people can know there is a working function.